# Scraping web contents from first two page and export scraped data to csv using python and BS4

Tags: python, pandas, csv, beautifulsoup

I m new to python and using Python 3.6.2 and I m trying to scrape data from first 2 page using a specific keyword. So far I m able to get the data into Python IDLE window, but I m facing difficulty in exporting data to CSV.I have tried using BeautifulSoup 4 and pandas but not able to export. Here is the so far what I have done. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
import csv   
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = "http://www.amazon.in/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-
alias%3Dautomotive&field-
keywords=helmets+for+men&rh=n%3A4772060031%2Ck%3Ahelmets+for+men&ajr=0"
request = requests.get(url)    
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content, "lxml")
#filename = auto.csv
#with open(str(auto.csv,"r+","\n")) as csvfile:
    #headers = "Count , Asin \n"
    #fo.writer(headers)
for url in soup.find_all('li'):
    Nand = url.get('data-asin')
    #print(Nand)   
    Result = url.get('id')
    #print(Result)
    #d=(str(Nand), str(Result))


df=pd.Index(url.get_attribute('url'))
#with open("auto.txt", "w",newline='') as dumpfile:
   #dumpfilewriter = csv.writer(dumpfile)
   #for Nand in soup:
       #value =  Nand.__gt__        
       #if value:
           #dumpfilewriter.writerows([value])
df.to_csv(dumpfile)
dumpfile.close()
csvfile.csv.writer("auto.csv," , ',' ,'|' , "\n")
```

Comment: Can someone please help me with this.Have been trying to export results to csv. I need "data-asin" and "id" in csv.

Comment: I forgot to add i m using python 3.6.2 version

Comment: fix your indentation, code cannot be executed

Comment: @Dmitriy Fialkovskiy I have done that while pasting the code lines have been misplaced..can you tell me where I m doing wrong? While exporting data to csv..?

Comment: click `edit` your post and make proper spaces line by line manually in parallell looking at the preview below edit window=)

Comment: the output which gives me is None
None
B00NXG86UE
result_0
B010M5MORO
result_1
B00OJZOBRA
result_2
B01JIJD4B0
result_3
B01M5DZU3D
result_4
B00NQ2P2HU
result_5
B01MTCMXFC
result_6
B019WFOVXU
result_7
B00NXFPUYU
result_8
B01IZBN4ZS
result_9
B0152XB2Q0
result_10
B00NQ2RN4A
result_11
B00NQ2RQXI
result_12
B00NXG11SI
result_13
B00QNSDZ6O
result_14
B00NQ2SYZM
result_15
B00OJZPNOA
result_16
B01BF3K4S8
result_17
B01JIKH2Q2
result_18
B01JIKGWR2
result_19
B01ALULL9C
result_20
B071VL8X2H
result_21
B00NXFWYO4
result_22
B072MNF5LS
result_23
None

Comment: But i want output as B00NXG86UE  in column A and  result_0 in column B. but in csv.. please help me fix this

Comment: give example of output in table view in question body as well, please

Comment: also, please do something with comments - do they create any value?should comments be _uncommented_ or they can be removed?

Comment: Help me with exporting the data of variable "Nand" and "Result" to csv file. if you want me to make changes in code please let me know. thanks in advance

Comment: the comments which i have added are just what i have tried using pandas module..but i did not get through my problem..can you help me creating new one with above url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `user-agent` in request to site to escape auto blocking bots. You got a lot of `None` because you didn't specify which precisely `<li>` tags do you want. I added it to code as well.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


url = "http://www.amazon.in/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dautomotive&field-keywords=helmets+for+men&rh=n%3A4772060031%2Ck%3Ahelmets+for+men&ajr=0"
request = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'})    
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content, "lxml")

res = []

for url in soup.find_all('li', class_ = 's-result-item'):
    res.append([url.get('data-asin'), url.get('id')])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=res, columns=['Nand', 'Result'])    
df.to_csv('path/where/you/want/to/store/file.csv')
```

**EDIT**: for processing all pages you need to build a loop that generates urls which you will then pass to main processing block (which you already have). Check out this page: `http://www.amazon.in/s/ref=sr_pg_2?rh=n%3A4772060031%2Ck%3Ahelmets+for+men&page=2&keywords=helmets+for+men&ie=UTF8&qid=1501133688&spIA=B01N0MAT2E,B01MY1ZZDS,B01N0RMJ1H`.

**EDIT_2**: let's loop on `page` parameter. You can manually add `page` to url which you pass to `requests.get()`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

base_url = "http://www.amazon.in/s/ref=sr_pg_2?rh=n%3A4772060031%2Ck%3Ahelmets+for+men&keywords=helmets+for+men&ie=UTF8"
#excluding page from base_url for further adding
res = []

for page in range(1,72): # such range is because last page for needed category is 71

    request = requests.get(base_url + '&page=' + str(page), headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'}) # here adding page    
    if request.status_code == 404: #added just in case of error
        break
    soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content, "lxml")

    for url in soup.find_all('li', class_ = 's-result-item'):
        res.append([url.get('data-asin'), url.get('id')])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=res, columns=['Nand', 'Result'])    
df.to_csv('path/where/you/want/to/store/file.csv')
```

Comment: @Nandish, any feedback? did my solution help?

Comment: Super..thanks for the code..it worked. i did forget about the class 's-result-item'.

Comment: is there a way where i can add next page to the result?..this was just for page 1..i would require page 2 dump as well.

Comment: please check answer now.

Comment: I tried adding loop for url as : url_template = "http://www.amazon.in/s/ref=%?url=search-alias%3Dautomotive&field-keywords=helmets+for+men&rh=n%3A4772060031%2Ck%3Ahelmets+for+men&ajr=0"
for ref in [1,2]:
    url=(url_template, refsr_pg_%)  replacing ref with % but its throughing syntax error..

Comment: there's another option through changing `page` parameter, I didn't notice it initially. It seems to be more right to change

Comment: But in first page there is no page parameter present. so do i need to add 'page=2' to the first url? if so i tried that..can give a for loop for the same? added with code?

Comment: can you please provide me the sample, because i m getting trouble while doing this

Comment: ok, i have changed range of page to (1,3) and when i run the code i m getting output of first page only in csv. do i need to add append in the df.to_csv('auto.csv') ?

Comment: Tried that but still showing up data from the base url page only. its not looping through page.

Comment: using my code i got last element as: res[-1] == ['B01HCPP0I2', 'result_1694']. it seems you're executing something wrongly.

Comment: Yes, it's showing output correct..actually, i made mistake in loop..thanks you so much..

Comment: @Nandish, can you explain why you unaccepted my answer?

Comment: check again - it's not in place, you can accept only one answer

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: Help me with exporting the data of variable "Nand" and "Result" to csv file

```
with open("auto.csv", 'w') as fh:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(fh, fieldnames=['Nand', 'Result'])
    writer.writeheader()
    data = {}
    for url in soup.find_all('li'):
        data['Nand'] = url.get('data-asin')
        data['Result'] = url.get('id')
        writer.writerow(data)
```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***

Comment: I m getting syntax error  as line 140, in __init__
    self.writer = writer(f, dialect, *args, **kwds)
TypeError: argument 1 must have a "write" method

Comment: it's ok stovfl. yes the code is working fine..thank you.